# Work out probability of event occurring after another given a sequence of events

Tags: probability

I have a log of events ordered by time, I need to approximate the probability of one event occurring after another given only this list. For example sequence of events is as follows:

**A**, **C**, **D**, **E**, **B**, **A**, **A**, **E**, **B**, **D**

I have tried working out the probability of Event **D** occuring given Event **B** has occurred.

P(**D**|**B**) = $\frac{1}{5}$ + $\frac{1}{1}$ = 1.2

I am not sure if I am going about this in a mathematically sound way. I am essentially trying to find the probability that Event **B** causes Event **D**.

Comment: Probabilities do not exceed $1$

Comment: There are two "immediately after B" events, one of which is D.  Alternatively, there are two D events, one of which is immediately preceded by B.  None of this implies causation

Comment: @Henry, hence I said that I am not sure my method is mathematically sound, once I got a value greater than 1 the alarm bells went off in my head.

Comment: If the sequence of events is given, then the probability that D occurs after B has no significance, because both have already happened. It is necessary at least to know the relationship between different events (are they independent for instance?), and to have a larger sample space than the sequence itself.

Comment: I think you want to delve into Statistics not probability. Probability is when you have a mathematical relation. Using Statistics you can "estimate" this probability from a sample (like event log). Am I clear?